# Creating a Joomla Test and Deploy Build Script

Tags: php, deployment, joomla, phing

I'm working on a Joomla Component. My IDE is Eclipse. And actually I want it to release it on the JED (Joomla Extension Directory).

To get the deployment automatically done I found a nice **Phing**-script which is able to create the zip and tar files. To do this I use the **fileset** feature of Phing to define all neccessary files.

```
<fileset dir="${src}" id="adminfiles">
    <include name="admin/admin.compname.php" />
    <include name="admin/controller.php" />
    <include name="admin/gpl-3.0.txt" />
</fileset>
```

Now I want to use this file list to copy all the files also to my test environment. Therefore I have to strip the folder name `admin/` from each filename in the list.
Is there any Phing-Task which can do this for me. Or any regex (uhahah).

Best regards
tria1312

Comment: What exactly so you want to do, can you give an example outcome?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it has anything to do with 'striping' of folder names. You just want to copy a bunch of files, right?

This would copy all files with the php extension from the admin folder to a folder of your choice:

```
<copy todir="${testPath}/test" overwrite="true">
    <fileset dir="admin">
        <include name="*.php" />
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

For more options see the [fileset type](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/chapters/appendixes/AppendixD-CoreTypes.html#Fileset).

Comment: OK, but I want to use filesets with folders and subfolders. `<fileset dir="${src}" id="sitefiles">
  <include name="site/interface.php" />
    </fileset>
 

 <copy todir="${test}/components/com_joomlacomp">
  <fileset refid="sitefiles" />
 </copy>` The result should be like this: **mypath/interface.php**. But it is: **mypath/site/interface**. So, I think there must be some kind of preprocessing within the copy task.